# Java JDBC -> SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I'm trying to have a Java application talk to a Microsoft SQL Server database.

- I downloaded sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu.tar.gz from the Microsoft web site as this isn't hosted in the normal Maven-style Java library repositories.
- I manually install in local Maven repository.
- I use the following super simple test code:
- I can access the database in SQLWorkbenchJ which is a Java based SQL query tool and get normal, instant responses to these SQL commands.
- The server is SQL Server 2005 on Windows 7.
- The client is Java 7. I've tried Java 8 as well with no difference.

  ```
      public static void superSimpleJdbcTest(String jdbcUrl, String user, String password) throws SQLException {

          try (Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, user, password)) {
              System.out.println("opened connection");

              try (Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement()) {
                  System.out.println("created statement");

                  System.out.println("executing create table command...");
                  statement.execute("create table something (id int primary key, name varchar(100))");
                  System.out.println("completed create table command");

                  System.out.println("executing insert command...");
                  statement.executeUpdate("insert into something (id, name) values (1, 'Brian')");
                  System.out.println("insert command completed");
              }
          }
      }
  ```

It sporadically works, but usually hangs on the create table command. If I comment out that, it hangs on the insert command. I can't imagine what is wrong.

Comment: What is the definition of "hangs" in this instance?

Comment: I wait several minutes and the statement.execute or statement.executeUpdate commands never return. These are trivial commands. When I run the same commands with other database tools, the server responds instantly.

Comment: *usually* its ok, but these drivers/version were originally written for Java 5/6, you're trying with 7 or 8 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774

Comment: Check the database logs.  If your code is connecting and not getting a response from the database it's quite likely the database is unhappy and expressed its unhappiness in a log entry.

Answer (score 0):

When the SQLWorkbenchJ application was running, my simple Java test app, would open the connection and just hang forever on any SQL command without getting any errors.

As soon as I quit the SQLWorkbenchJ application, my simple Java test app ran perfectly as expected. That was really weird and I eventually stumbled on the answer.

I switched over to using RazorSQL as an SQL console and that doesn't seem to have any issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used both the [JTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) and the Microsoft driver (JDBC4). I have not tried the ***SQLWorkbenchJ***, as I mostly use [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) to test the drivers.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11194392)

Comment: Good advice. Thanks!